# Pokestop didn't appear even after 2 days of approval but Ingress portals are live

Tags: pokemon-go

I have been adding new Pokestops in my deserted town (PokemonGo perspective of view) for a month and I have never encountered what I have experienced recently.

I nominated 2 stops and both of them got accepted. Two days passed and the Ingress portals are online, but the Pokestops in PokemonGo are missing.

Some readers may think that this has happened because the stops were too close to existing ones but there is an average distance of 600m between the old and new Pokestops.

So what might the problem be?

Is there any solution?

Comment: What I wonder is how do you know if a pokestop is accepted? My SO did throw a few in and what it seemed to be was a black box that you put your submission in and at somepoint it might appear.

Comment: @Fredy31 you should get an email, but it can take months to get a stop approved.

Comment: #Fredy31 I got email and also checked my wayfarer account where I got orange shashes on the nomination. Besides , ingress portals are live.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Niantic is currently upgrading all of their backend systems to the latest version of Lightship, which is preventing the waypoint sync systems from running effectively. Here's a direct quote from [their most recent update.](https://community.ingress.com/en/discussion/16303/update-on-portal-nominations-edits-and-photo-submissions)

> Due to upgrades we are making to the backend, Portal nominations, and photo submissions and edits will be delayed for several weeks, and we are actively working to address this. Please note that you do not need to submit these nominations/edits/photos again.

Under typical operation this data would sync 5 times per week. My guess would be that this upgrade was started in the short period *after* the Ingress portals went live, but *before* the regularly scheduled synchronisation process ran, leading to the waypoints appearing in Ingress but not in Pokemon Go.

Answer (score -3):

What is important to know is that in Pokemon go, the map is not updated every day, in realtime. Its only updated once every few months to add pokestops, and remove those who were requested.

So if you can see a pokestop as 'Accepted' in whatever way you check them, it probably means that it will show up in the next update.

And when is the next update? We don't know. they are infrequent and not announced. https://thesilphroad.com/science/openstreetmap-problems-pokemon-go/

Comment: This information is incorrect. Under normal operations waypoints sync daily (on weekdays). You may be thinking of OSM data (i.e., the actual map, not waypoints), which is updated very infrequently.

Comment: So then I would guess it might be accepted in the system, but is awaiting the next map update to get pushed to the systems.

Comment: Very incorrect. In my town, new pokestops get created at 11:30 PM (IST) everyday